# Email first authentication with React and Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication, jsx

Here is a simple code in reactjs that requires the user to enter both their email and password to log in to the website:

```
import { useState } from "react"
import { auth } from "./firebase-config"
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth"
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"

export default function LogIn(){
    setLogEmail that can be used to update the value of logPass
    const [logEmail, setLogEmail] = useState('')
    const [logPass, setLogPass] = useState('')

    const navigate = useNavigate()

    const logIn = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, logEmail, logPass)
        .then((user) => {
            console.log(user)
            navigate('/home')
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={logIn}>
                <h3>Log In</h3>
                <input
                    type="email"
                    placeholder="enter email"
                    onChange={(e) => {setLogEmail(e.target.value)}}
                >
                </input>
                <input
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="Enter Password"
                    onChange={(e) => {setLogPass(e.target.value)}}
                ></input>
                <button type="submit">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Now, this works just fine... but for my website, I want to authenticate the email and the password on a different page. Here's how I require the authentication process to be constructed:

1. Display Log In page with only email input
2. The user inputs their email and selects submit
3. The system verifies if the email exists in the database.
4. If the email exists, navigate to the password page where the password authentication takes place.
5. Else if the email does not exist, navigate to a page where the user creates an account.

Is there a way to authenticate the email and password separately?